# difference between pipe line operators %>% and |> in R?

Tags: r, data.table, pipeline, magrittr

I was thinking of stop using magrittr library since now we have `|>` operator.
But apparently they are not the same - the new operator produces error. See below

```
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

diamonds %>%  setDT  
# runs ok

diamonds |>  setDT
# doesnot run
> Error: The pipe operator requires a function call as RHS
```

Is that supposed to be that way?

When is it recommended to use `%>%` vs. `|>` ?

Comment: You would need to use `diamonds |>  setDT()`. The native pipe require a function call, not just a function name.

Comment: The error message was very clear to those who understand the terminology used in R. Notice that the SO formatting turned the letters "call" in red, indicating that it was a language term. A naked `setDT` is not a "call". It is a function name. At a minimum an R call will have matching parentheses. Look at the docs: `?is.call`